# SQL Server - Sum(Log()) when one value is 0

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have this following table in SQL Server (2012):

```
MyTable:
Date:         Return:
1/1/2016      0.1 
1/2/2016      0.2
1/3/2016      -0.3 
1/4/2016      -1
```

And I'm trying to get the cumulative return over the date period which can be done via the formula `Cumulative Return = PRODUCT(1+Return(i)) - 1`.

Doing so in SQL Server, where there is no easy way to compute a product, I'm using the fact that, mathematically, `X*Y*Z = EXP(LOG(X) + LOG(Y)  +LOG(Z)))`, so I can do the following via a query:

```
SELECT
   EXP(SUM(LOG(1 + [RETURN]))) - 1 as CumulativeReturn
FROM
   MyTable
```

And this works **until I have a single value that equals -1 (-100% return)** - In which case I:

1. Would like the entire `CumulativeReturn` to equal -1
2. Get the error `An invalid floating point operation occurred.` since one of my values is `LOG(0)` which throws that error

My question is how can I get my `CumulativeReturn` to equal -1 if any of the values for return = `-1` in the most efficient way?

The only thing I could think of would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
   CASE 
     WHEN EXISTS
        (SELECT [RETURN] FROM MyTable WHERE [RETURN] = -1)
     THEN -1
     ELSE EXP(SUM(LOG(1 + [RETURN]))) - 1 
   END as CumulativeReturn
FROM
   MyTable
```

But I'm really hoping there is a better way to do this since this is a very simplified example of my real situation and adding in this logic would be ugly and, I'm afraid, inefficient due to all the sub-queries I'd be doing for each such column / grouping.

Comment: Is writing a CLR custom aggregate within your comfort area/range of possible solutions?

Comment: .. I'm slowly starting to think it might have to be, @Damien_The_Unbeliever... Also looking into doing it via CTEs instead....

Comment: Mathematically the equivalence is sound, but I should think this solution can easily run into accuracy problems when actual floating-point values are involved. This problem is practically the poster child for a custom CLR aggregate. CTEs couldn't be expected to improve on the implementation's efficiency, and would certainly be a lot harder to read (since you need to track the "error state" of the calculation separately).

Comment: So, CLR Aggregate here we go.... :) Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, based upon the suggestions given in the comments above and the limitations of the `LOG()` function, I ended up creating a CLR Aggregate function in C# based upon the sample code provided [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170061/Custom-Aggregates-in-SQL-Server) which worked perfectly.

Of course, if anyone else has any ideas on how to do this directly via SQL, I'd love to hear about it for furthering my knowledge / people who aren't comfortable with programming, but this did do the trick for me.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there! The problem has to do with the cockamamie way SQL Server evaluates expressions -- even those that are supposed to be short circuited. If you write it this way, it will work:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN (SELECT MIN([RETURN]) FROM Mytable) <= -1 THEN -1
ELSE (SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(1+ [RETURN]))) - 1 FROM Mytable)
END as CumulativeReturn
```

Also, as @jeroen-mostert correctly pointed out, SQL Server floating-point calculations are not exact. Also, you may wish to put an index on [RETURN] to improve performance.

Comment: This will scan the table twice, unless there is an index on `[RETURN]`. Also, the query is supposed to result in `-1`, not `0`, if there is any `-1` (easily fixed). The issues with the limits of floating-point accuracy will remain; this is very likely to not yield an exact product.